# Unity 3d how to instantiate object in a certian position

Tags: unity-game-engine

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playSound : MonoBehaviour {

```
private bool destructionHasBegun = false;
public Transform BlueKey;


private void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    audio.Play ();
    destructionHasBegun = true;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(destructionHasBegun)
    {
        DestroyWhenSoundComplete();
    }
}

private void DestroyWhenSoundComplete()
{
    if(!audio.isPlaying)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        GameObject textObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("BlueKey")); 





    }
}
```

}

im trying to instantiate the bluekey prefab in a particular position how do i do this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [`Instantiate` documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html), you can pass in a Vector3 worldspace position as a second parameter.

You'll also need to pass in a Quaternion for its initial rotation as the third parameter; [`Quaternion.identity`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-identity.html) is the equivalent of no rotation.

```cs
Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.identity;
GameObject textObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("BlueKey"), newPosition, newRotation);
```

Comment: im getting this error 'UnityEngine.Vector3' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' (CS0118) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: @user3482470 Ah, apologies, forgot to write `new` in front of the Vector3 constructor. Please see the updated code.